# Is there an npm module for markerclusterer that can be used by webpack to build a simple browser app?

Tags: npm, webpack, markerclusterer

Although an amateur with npm and webpack, I have successfully built other deliverables for my browser app. I also have a non-npm working version of google maps using the `markerclusterer.js` from github.

The npm  modules I have found are `google-maps-markerclusterer` and `markerclustererplus`.

There is no documentation for these modules - how to use them, or if they can be applied to browser apps. I have done a fair amount of unsuccessful searching online.

I have been unable to figure out how to import either module into my `map.ts` and how to instantiate the `MarkerClusterer`.

When installed via npm, the `node_modules` contain `.js` code that is not modular, so;

```js
import {MarkerClusterer} from 'markerclustererplus';
```

doesn't work: My VSC error is;

> `... is not a module.`

I am not running any frameworks at this time - just straightforward php and js code. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

First:

`npm i @agm/js-marker-clusterer`

You can use this one in you .ts:

`import { AgmJsMarkerClustererModule } from '@agm/js-marker-clusterer';`

In the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/js-marker-clusterer) you can find a good example of how to use it in your HTML.

[Source github](https://github.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer)

Comment: Thank you. It appears the offered solution is for an Angular project, and requires additional npm installs. I am not using Angular or any other framework. Can this be adopted in a standard js environment?

Comment: Yes you can.
I think you have to replace import with require.